# Is it possible to make a Git commit on another branch without changing branches?

Tags: git

I am working on branch `feature-a`, and I need to make a change to `feature-b` on an unrelated part of the source code. I forgot (or was too lazy) to make a secondary work tree, and edited some files that should be changed in the `feature-b` branch.

I could now make a worktree and `rsync` my uncommitted changes to the worktree. Or I could make my changes on the current branch and then `git-cherry-pick`/`git-rebase` them into the right place.

But really I just want to be able to make a commit on `feature-b` that reflects my edits, without actually changing the branch, switching out the contents of the main working tree, etc.

Is this possible with the Git CLI?

Comment: Ever heard of `git stash`? If you're using `rsync` for some workflow within a single git repository, then you're doing something wrong. 1. `git stash` everything unrelated to the changes you want on `feature-b`, if anything. 2. `git stash` what you want on `feature-b`. 3. Switch to `feature-b`. 4. `git-stash pop`. 5. commit & push 6. switch back to `feature-a`. 7. `git stash pop` if you did anything in #1.

Comment: Sure, and you could `git stash` across worktrees too (at least I think you can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. But you will have to use git low-level commands (a.k.a. [git plumbing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain)). The basic tasks would be:

- create new objects for the changed files (`git hash-object -w`)
- create new trees for the directories containing the changed files (`git write-tree`)
- create a new commit object referencing the tree for the root directory and the appropriate parent commit (`git commit-tree`)
- move the branch to that new commit
- push the branch

Note that for the last two steps you can use high-level git-commands, the first three are the tricky ones.

The example in [chapter 10.2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) does pretty much what you want.

Comment: Not exactly ergonomic! I noticed recently that there is a tool called Dura which makes commits in the background for you, on a separate branch. It seems like it does something along these lines: https://github.com/tkellogg/dura/blob/a2b95c/src/snapshots.rs#L19-L59

Comment: @shadowtalker That is an interesting tool and it in fact implements the workflow outlined above (except for the push). However I totally agree that doing it manually on the command line is not ergonomic for everyday use. It would definitly be worth its own script if you need it on a regular basis.